# How to use Lyzr SDKs

Tags: openai-api

I am trying to use lyzr sdks for my projects if anyone has some information on how to use Generators affectively, please reply

https://docs.lyzr.ai/homepage

How should be some simple queries to be passed to csvanalyzr and insights ?

I have tried with Generators it seems there is some error in the SDK.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This demo Google Colab file from the [official documentation](https://docs.lyzr.ai/Lyzr%20SDKs/data-analyzr) should answer your question: [colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RZDaPrWWw-ZKRNZaa-JvjrnVkuFmyrRd?usp=sharing)

The `Generator` module goes hand in hand with `DataAnalyzr`

1. **Using Generators**: This module can help you create sample queries or provide a brief description of your dataset. After you've loaded your CSV dataset into the generator, you can use the following methods:

   - `ai_queries_df`: This provides sample queries based on your data.
   - `describe_dataset`: Offers a brief description of your dataset.
2. **Using DataAnalyzr**: Once you have queries, you can use DataAnalyzr to analyze the data or generate visual representations:

   - `getAnalysis`: Returns the analysis of your data based on a user query.
   - `getVisualizations`: Creates visualizations based on your data.

For more detailed examples, the [official documentation](https://docs.lyzr.ai/Lyzr%20SDKs/data-analyzr) is a great resource.

If you're looking for community support, consider joining the [Discord channel](https://discord.gg/pDC6rFf8)